# What is the best way to import images as texture, then render out at original size?

Tags: rendering, uv-image-editor

I'm using Blender as a tool to warp packaging labels, then taking the render into Photoshop for compositing onto the photographed product.

When I load the label as an image texture in the UV window I want to make sure that I'm not sizing the file up beyond the original dimensions. I check this by first importing the art as an image plane, and using this to size the bottle shape to match it.

Is this a valid way to do this? What would a better method be?

Comment: Could you show us with pictures what your goal so far has been? I don't really understand what you would like to get

Comment: I believe you can do this in the current version of Photoshop.

Comment: I just jumped to Photoshop CC, and haven't gotten comfortable with the 3D tools there. But yes, that would be a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a better way than your method, there is no direct relation between pixels and blender units, and the rendering process will always compute new values from the texture's pixel data and adjust depending on the camera's view angle.

If you know what the label's print dimensions are ,you can set the [DPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch) of the  image in the addon's import options, which is great since it also preserves the aspect ratio.

[image]

If you want to load the image in the UV directly with the correct aspect ratios ,just set the display aspect ratio to the image dimensions , there is also a visual tool to check which faces are being stretched, but none to check up/down scaling sadly.

[image]